# DASH 2.0 datatable issue with fixed colum and header row when filtering

Tags: css, filter, datatable, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a dash app that uses a datatable.  I have the first/header row fixed and one of the columns fixed.  When I have both fixed and I try to use the filter row and I try to search for an item that doesn't exist in the datatable, it returns a collapsed datatable.  The visual looks odd.  Is there a way to fix this?  Seems like a bug when you have filter row enabled, header row fixed, and columns fixed.

[image: Example]

please see datatable code below.  pretty standard stuff.  I thin there is a bug with the library that needs to be patched:

```
dash_table.DataTable(
            id='table',
            [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in dff.columns],
            style_data={'border': '1px solid black', 'whiteSpace': 'normal', 'padding': '.5rem',
                        'height': 'auto', 'width': 'auto', 'backgroundColor': '#3D4146', 'color': 'white',
                        'fontSize': '20px'},
            fixed_columns={'headers': True, 'data': 1},  # 'headers': True,
            data=dff.to_dict('records'),
            editable=False,
            export_format="csv",
            virtualization=False,
            fixed_rows={'headers': True},
            filter_action="native",
            filter_options={"case": "insensitive"},
            sort_action="native",  # give user capability to sort columns
            sort_mode="single",  # sort across 'multi' or 'single' columns
            page_action='none',
            style_table={'height': '85vh', 'maxHeight': '85vh',
                         'padding-bottom': '10px', 'box-shadow': '5px 5px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39)'},
            style_cell={'textAlign': 'left', 'minWidth': '235px',
                        'width': 'auto', 'maxWidth': '360px', 'fontSize': '16px', 'minHeight': '150px',
                        'color': 'black'},
            style_header={
                'backgroundColor': '#272B30',
                'fontWeight': 'bold',
                'fontSize': '18px',
                'color': 'white',
                'border': '1px solid black'
            },
        )
```

Comment: Can you include the code you've used to produce what you have so far? this will help us debug your code much more easily

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.